# Convert two digit year to four digits and also support one or two digit month

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat, date-format

I want to convert two digits year to four digits and also it is possible to come 4 digits

```
        final Integer year = 2020;
        final Integer month = 12;
        final DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMyy", Locale.US);
        final Date monthAndYear = originalFormat.parse(month + String.valueOf(year));
        final DateFormat formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM", Locale.US);

        System.out.println(formattedDate.format(monthAndYear));
```

This code fails if the input is 2-2020, which not parsing one digit month.

I want to pass the code by below conditions

```
        year       | month       || expeected
        2020       | 12          || "2020-12"
        30         | 2           || "2030-02"
        41         | 05          || "2041-05"
```

Comment: What if you have `1999` or `99` for year?

Comment: I need to return 1999. But for my case it will be future year

Comment: In your example for `41` you expect `2041` why for `99` you expect `1999`?

Comment: for 99, 2099 is ok. But if it come as 1999, need to return as 1999. For my case, I will get input as future year

Comment: I edit my answer and for your case `YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.of(Year.parse("2022", YEAR_FORMAT).getValue(), 5);` it work fine with my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `YearMonth` for this like so:

```
final DateTimeFormatter YEAR_FORMAT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[yyyy][yy]");
YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.of(
        Year.parse(year, YEAR_FORMAT).getValue(),
        month);
```

Note: The year should be a String

Outputs:

```
2020-12
2030-02
2041-05
```

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think I’d want to use parsing for this, though it is an option. Your year and month come as numbers, so I find it more natural to handle them as such. Like the others I recommend using `YearMonth` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

```
    final Integer year = 2020;
    final Integer month = 12;
    
    YearMonth monthAndYear;
    if (0 <= year && year < 100) { // two digits
        YearMonth currentMonthAndYear = YearMonth.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        // Truncate current year to whole centuries
        int fullYear = currentMonthAndYear.getYear() / 100 * 100 + year;
        monthAndYear = YearMonth.of(fullYear, month);
        if (monthAndYear.isBefore(currentMonthAndYear)) { // in the past, wrong
            monthAndYear = monthAndYear.plusYears(100);
        }
    } else {
        monthAndYear = YearMonth.of(year, month);
    }
    
    System.out.println(monthAndYear);
```

Output from this example snippet:

> 2020-12

It’s wordier than the code in the other answers. The upside is that it gives us precise control over which century to use for two digit years. Year 20 and moth 4 give us `2120-04`, while year 20 and month 9 give us `2020-09`. So both are in the future.

You want the result as a string in the format from your question? We’re lucky, `YearMonth.toString()` gives us that.

```
    System.out.println(monthAndYear.toString());
```

The format is ISO 8601.

**Link:** [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Hi @Ole, Why you think When Year 20 and moth 4 the result should be `2120-04`? isn't against the OP requirement ?

Comment: @YCF_L OP will have to decide. If we are to take *I will get input as future year* literally, you are correct. I believe that the code can be modified to what is intended. I hope OP will clarify further.

Answer (score 1):

Use single `M` for a month in the format. A single `M` holds good for any allowed number of digits for a month in the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). You should stop using the broken and outdated `java.util` date-time API and switch to the modern date-time API.

```
import java.time.YearMonth;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M-[uuuu][uu]");

        // Test strings (month-year)
        String[] ymStrArr = { "2-2020", "2-20", "02-2020", "02-20" };
        for (String ymStr : ymStrArr) {
            YearMonth ym = YearMonth.parse(ymStr, formatter);
            System.out.println(ym);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-02
2020-02
2020-02
2020-02
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String pattern = "";
        if(year1.length() == 4){
            pattern = "yyyy";
        }elif(year1.length() == 2){
            pattern = "yy[yy]";
        }
        
        YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.of(Year.parse(year1, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern)).getValue(),month);  
        System.out.println(yearMonth);
```